Why is the nvm cache folder (.nvm ) so large? Can I delete it?
Currently my nvm folder (~/.nvm) is very large - over 21 GB. It seems to cache a lot of data.
I would like to save space on my drive. Can this cache be deleted? If I delete it,what impact will it have?

You can use nvm cache clear to delete nvm's cache, that should free up most of the space.
nvm is caching the build files for arm64, deleting them shouldn't cause any problem, more details in this Github issue.
Thanks to user uchar for this answer.
